# 2d character array in c not being written to properly

Tags: c

I am new to programming in C, and haven't quite gotten used to not having strings yet. The code below will write the first word into Arguments[0] correctly, but all other words won't be written in correctly, and I have no idea why. Could someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, int **argv)
{
    /*Get input and store it in str*/
    char str[100];
    if( fgets(str, 100, stdin) != NULL)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        perror("Null input");
    }

    /*Parse input into separate arguments*/
    int numArg = 0;
    int wordStart = 0;
    int wordEnd = 0;
    bool wordStarted = false;
    char Arguments[30][100];
    /*iterate through str*/
    for(int i =0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        /*if we're reading a character that isn't a space and we aren't parsing a word yet*/
        /*required special case for beginning of input not being a space*/
        if(i==0 && str[i] != ' ' || str[i] != ' ' && wordStarted == false)
        {
            /*set this spot in array to be the start of a word*/
            wordStart = i;
            /*set boolean so that we are parsing a word*/
            wordStarted = true;
        }
        /*if we're parsing a word, and we see a space or see the line end*/
        else if(str[i] == ' ' && wordStarted == true || str[i] == '\n')
        {
            /*set this spot in array to be the end of a word*/
            wordEnd = i;
            /*put word into *Arguments*/
            for(int k = 0; k < (wordEnd - wordStart); k++)
            {
                Arguments[numArg][k+wordStart] = str[k+wordStart];
            }
            /*add null character to end*/
            Arguments[numArg][k+wordStart] = '\0';
            /*increase number of arguments by 1*/
            numArg++;
            /*set boolean so that we are no long parsing a word*/
            wordStarted = false;
        }
    }
    printf("numArg is %d\n", numArg);
    int j = 0;
    for(j; j < numArg; j++)
    {
        printf("Argument %d is: %s\n", j, Arguments[j]);
    }
}
```

If I were to run this code and then type:

```
there are four words
```

the output would be:

```
numArg is 4
Argument 0 is: there
Argument 1 is:
Argument 2 is:
Argument 3 is:`
```

I can't figure out why the output isn't:

```
numArg is 4
Argument 0 is: there
Argument 1 is: are
Argument 2 is: four
Argument 3 is: words
```

Comment: What is the first `i` supposed to mean in `for (i; ... )`? Also, on `fgets()` failure you just print the error and continue, why?

Comment: the `i` keeps track of my spot as I iterate through str, and the perror was added later when I was attempting (and failing) at debugging

Comment: You can declare it in the `for` statement and initilize it there, I have never seen what you did because it does not make sense. Please enable compiler warnings, you also have ambigous comparisons because you are not using parentheses for logical operators, and you are using many condtions which is confusing.

Comment: `if (i == 0 ...` will not deal with multiple leading whit spaces. Also, you iterate through 100 characters but you might read 10 or 20 only, so you potentially are reading uninitialized data which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I will try to find the end of words and exit the loop immediately after.

Comment: You can skip all white space characters first, and start looping at the first non white-space. Also, surround operators with white spaces so that this `k+wordStart` doesn't look like a single identifier.

Comment: I will do that. I added a catch to exit the loop immediately at the end of str.

Comment: Do you know what c uses as a space character? I think the problem might be cause because a space might not be equivalent to a ' ' character. Either that or my if statement conditions are completely messed up. I will go investiage. I appreciate your help thus far. Is there a way to give you points?

Comment: No, it's not ... A space is indeed equivalent to `' '`, you should consider other white-space characters like tab `'\t'` though, for that you can use `isspace()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and also try to understand the code and see why your code is not working, since there are multiple reasons I think it will be more helpful to show you a simple working implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *last;
    char *pointer;
    char text[100];
    int count;
    char words[30][100];

    if ((pointer = fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin)) == NULL)
        return -1;
    while ((*pointer != '\0') && (isspace((int) *pointer) != 0))
        ++pointer;
    count = 0;
    last = pointer;
    while (*pointer != '\0')
    {
        if (isspace((int) *pointer) != 0)
        {
            size_t length;

            length = pointer - last;
            memcpy(words[count], last, length);

            words[count][length] = '\0';

            last = pointer + 1;
            count += 1;
        }
        ++pointer;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "There are %d words\n\n", count);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
        fprintf(stdout, "\t%d: %s\n", i + 1, words[i]);
}
```

I wasn't very careful so this might have a lot of problems, but it's a simple way to do what you want, for example I can think of multiple spaces between "*words*", this code will not deal with that correctly, but as a said it will do what you want more or less.